# Run Azure Durable Function Asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions

I'm trying to run an async function in Azure and as far as I have seen, this is done using the durable functions in Azure. I have been working with the [tutorial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode) from Microsoft but it doesn't seem to actually run asynchronously.

This is the constructor demo

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity('E1_SayHello', "Tokyo")
    result2 = yield context.call_activity('E1_SayHello', "Seattle")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity('E1_SayHello', "London")
    return [result1, result2, result3]

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

and this is the function being called

```
def main(name: str) -> str:
    logging.info(f"Hello {name}!")
    return f"Hello {name}!"
```

That works fine and you quickly get the three responses of "Hello {City}!" that you would expect. But it appears to be calling it one at a time, waiting for the response in between. If you change the function slightly and put a sleep function in it like below, each response is 10 seconds apart where the desired result is that they would all be called at the same time and then wait on the results for all 3.

```
def main(name: str) -> str:
    time.sleep(10)
    logging.info(f"Hello {name}!")
    return f"Hello {name}!"
```

I've tried replacing context.call_activity with context.wait_for_external_event but this has similar results and a number of the sections of the documentation are in C# and JavaScript only so I don't know if there is just no equivalent for Python or if it just isn't documented fully.

The end goal is to be able to make a number of API calls (60+) with various parameters held in a list, clean the data before writing to a database. Currently it's taking just shy of 60 seconds per API call so would like to run them in an async pattern so it doesn't take close to an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to this via their [Github sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/tree/dev/samples) so I'll put it here just in case anyone else is searching.

you need to put the context.call_activity functions into a list first and then use that list as the function variable in yield context.task_all as per below.

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    tasks = []
    cities = ["Tokyo", "Seattle", "London"]
    for city in cities:
        tasks.append(context.call_activity('Hello', city))

    results = yield context.task_all(tasks)
    return results
```