# Should I define an azure activity function as async in python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, python-asyncio, azure-durable-functions

Azure functions documentation recommends defining python functions as asynchronous using the `async` keyword and async packages in the function body to take advantage of concurrent execution. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference#async)

I can not find any mention of the same for activity functions (those triggered with the `activityTrigger`) that are called by durable function orchestrators (using `yield`). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale)

Should I define an azure activity function as async in Python, as well? Why or why not?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @mohamed-azarudeen-z Thanks for grammar eddits but I do mean to say: _activity functions that are called from within durable function orchestrators_

Answer (score 0):

**According to this [**MS Document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints.md#python-coroutines)**

> Python orchestrator functions cannot be declared as coroutines. Therefore, never declare a Python orchestrator function with the 'async' keyword since coroutine semantics do not match the Durable Functions replay model. The 'context' API will utilize 'yield' rather than 'await' since Python orchestrator functions must always be declared as generators.

**Async http trigger function:-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = await req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Success",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Refer this [**SO Thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228541/run-azure-durable-function-asynchronously)  on yield activity function by Paul Clarke***

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. However, I am interested more in the activity functions, triggered by `activityTrigger` not orchestrators. 

From my understanding an orchestrator yield would put a task into the Task Hub. It is then picked up by one of worker processes. Can/should that activity be defined as `async`? It seems that would make sense if it helps for ordinary (not durable ones) python azure functions to run concurrently.

Comment: Python orchestrator functions cannot be specified as coroutines, according to the Microsoft document - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints.md. Due to the fact that coroutine semantics do not adhere to the Durable Functions replay model, it is never advisable to declare a Python orchestrator function with the 'async' keyword. Python orchestrator functions must be defined as generators at all times, so the "context" API will use "yield" rather than "await."

Comment: However, there is no mention of this requirement in the documentation for activity functions. Therefore, if it helps for common (non-durable) python azure functions to execute concurrently, you can declare an Azure activity function in Python as async.
In conclusion, if a durable function orchestrator calls an Azure activity function, you shouldn't declare it in Python as async.

Comment: Sorry, but you just contradicted yourself in your last comment. In one sentence you say that
 _you can declare an Azure activity function in Python as async_
Then in the next one you say  that 
_you shouldn't declare it in Python as async_
Which is it then?